# How to find out the process(es) that forks a lot?

Tags: shell, process, monitoring, fork

Recently I got an load-too-high issue on our server. I watched `top` for like half an hour to find out that it was Nagios that forked a lot of short-lived processes. After bouncing Nagios, everything was back to normal.

My question here is, how to find out the root process that forks a lot like this more quickly?

Thanks.

Comment: Hopefully you're aware that nagios, as a monitoring system, spawns monitoring processes (on a schedule, albeit internally-determined)?

Comment: Yes, but when the issue happened, the children were way more than usual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you run an OS that supports `dtrace`, this script will help you identifying what processes are launching short lived processes:

```
#!/usr/sbin/dtrace -qs

proc:::exec
{
  self->parent=stringof((unsigned char*)curpsinfo->pr_psargs);
}

proc:::exec-success
/self->parent != NULL/
{
  printf("%s -> %s\n",self->parent,curpsinfo->pr_psargs);
  self->parent=NULL;
}
```

If you are on an OS without `dtrace` support, have a look to alternatives, e.g. [`systemtap`](https://sourceware.org/systemtap/) or [`sysdig`](http://www.sysdig.org/) with Linux, [`ProbeView`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ProbeVue) with AIX.

Here is a `sysdig` script that will show all commands launch and exit times with their `pid` and `ppid`:

```
sysdig -p"*%evt.time %proc.pid %proc.ppid %evt.dir %proc.exeline" \
    "( evt.dir=< and evt.type=execve ) or evt.type=procexit"
```

Another method would be to enable process accounting with your OS (if available, commonly the `acct` package under Linux) and have a look to the generated logs. There is also a `top` like program that leverage process accounting: [atop](http://www.atoptool.nl/).

Answer (score 2):

Try `top -Sd1`. This will show the cumulative time of each process instead of just its own. Cumulative here stands for the time a process has consumed, plus the time its children that don't exist any more consumed.

Normally, the process that goes up faster (and probably the one that's already high enough) is the one you're looking for. After that you can strace the process to verify your suspicion.

Comment: This is a way I can use, may not for this certain issue. Thanks.

Comment: niiiiiiiiiiice!

Answer (score 0):

`ps ej |cut -d" " -f1 |sort |uniq -c`

In fact, `ps ej` display the parent Pid of process, so if a process fork a lot all his children will have the same Ppid.

`cut -d" " -f1` is there to only keep the first field of the ps output, then `sort` the data , and finally `uniq -c` will display the number of occurence of each uniq pid .

You can also have a awk only version with counting occurence with an array : 
`ps ejx |awk -n '{count[$1]++}END{for(j in count) print "process:" j, "("count[j]")"}'`

Comment: I'm afraid `ps`, just like `top`, will miss most short lived processes.

Comment: I actually tried something like this. One has to be lucky enough to caught those short lived processes.